# Chain rule for mutual information

Tags: information-theory

I am a bit confused in the following definition:
[image]

what does comma mean. I know I(X;Y) is the mutual information between X and Y but I am not sure how to interpret the I(X_1,X_2;Y)).

Comment: This is *not* a definition. It is a true mathematical statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$I(X_1,X_2;Y)$ is $I(X;Y)$, where $X = (X_1,X_2)$.

For example, suppose that $X_1,Y$ are two independent uniformly random bits, and $X_2 = X_1 \oplus Y$. Then $I(X_1;Y) = 0$ while $I(X_1,X_2;Y) = 1$.

In more detail, the joint distribution of $(X_1,X_2,Y)$ is the uniform distribution over the vectors $(0,0,0),(0,1,1),(1,0,1),(1,1,0)$. The variables $X_1$ and $Y$ are independent, and so $I(X_1;Y) = 0$. In contrast, the variable $(X_1,X_2)$ (which ranges over $\{0,1\}^2$) determines $Y$, and so $H(Y|X_1,X_2) = 0$. Consequently, $$I(X_1,X_2;Y) = H(Y) - H(Y|X_1,X_2) = H(Y) = 1.$$

Comment: Just to clarify how to interpret (X_1, X_2)? Does it mean Cartesian product of X_1 and X_2? And does XOR mean Cartesian product?

Comment: It’s a two-dimensional random variable. XOR means XOR.

Comment: 'XOR means XOR': that means all the variables here are binary variable right?

Comment: That's right, $X_1,X_2,Y$ are bits.

Comment: Alright thanks for the clarification